# How to import a class exported from a module?

Tags: typescript

I have typescript file (generated) that I'm using in my angular project.

The content of this file **contracts.ts** is as following:

```
export module A.B.C.Models {
  export class Activity {
    prop1: number;
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use these classes in another file in the same folder but I can't figure out how to properly import the classes and I'd also like to alias the module name that is way too long.

```
import { Activity } from './contracts';
```

The code doesn't compile with the folowing error:

> Can't find module 'contracts'

I can't modify the generated file as it is generated each time our database model changes.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `import all from './contracts';` and see what inside `console.log(all)`

Comment: I've modified my question, this is a compile time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old typescript feature called internal modules or namespaces (`export module A.B.C.Models` is the same as `export namespace A.B.C.Models`). You could import and use the class like this:

```
import * as c from './contracts'

c.A.B.C.Models.Activity
```

I recommend against it though. It is not recommend to mix JS modules and namespaces. See [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30994) on the topic:

> Namespaces are probably never going away and, simultaneously, you probably shouldn't use them, since better, more standard and modern patterns exist through the use of modules. If you have code that you feel needs to use a namespace, more power to you and go for it, but most of the time you don't need one, as we now have a different conceptual organizational model recommended for large-scale JS (modules).

Export the class directly and you will be able to use it with the `import` syntax:

```
//contacts.ts
export class Activity {
  prop1: number;
   ...
}
//usage.ts
import { Activity } from './contracts';
```

Comment: './contracts' is not seen as a module. I still have the can't find module error

Comment: Woops, VS 2017 let me include the file as a link to the project which explains why he can't resolve it.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT glad you figured the "add as link" issue, that would have been hard to guess.